# Javascript loop through an array of objects and return the first value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have created a function that is supposed to loop through an array of objects and return the first value of each object.

```js
function getSheetSectionData(name){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var data = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++){
      var obj = {};
      obj = sheetData[i][0];
      return sheetData[i][0];
  }
      data.push(obj);
}
```

It's only returning the first item in the first row/column. Any clues on what I'm missing?

Comment: You only execute the loop once and the you break from it by returning the value.

Comment: if its to be used as a custom function, none of the answers will work.

Comment: @ZigMandel what do you mean by that?

Comment: first confirm you plan to use as a custom function (called from a cell formula)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your intent is, but probably it should be something like this?

```
function getSheetSectionData(name){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++){
      var obj = {};
      obj = sheetData[i][0];
      data.push(obj);
  }

  return data;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @grogx noted below, creation of a temporary object appears unnecessary in this context and the sample above could be optimized to

```
function getSheetSectionData(name){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++){
      data.push(sheetData[i][0]);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Which can further be shortened to

```
function getSheetSectionData(name){
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName(name)
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map((e) => e[0]);
}
```

However, we do not really know, what the original intent of the OP was. It may be the case, that that temporary object was indeed required for some sort of intermediate transformation, which was striped out from the MCVE.

Comment: Why create a new object "obj"?? there's no need of doing that. You already have objects coming back!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.keys` together with `Array#map` to get just the first key value from each object.

```
data = sheetData.map(v => v[Object.keys(v)[0]]);
```

Working example:

```js
var arr = [{foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},{foo: 'war', bar: 'foo'},{foo: 'mar', bar: 'foo'}],
    res = arr.map(v => v[Object.keys(v)[0]]);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var sheetData = [{name : "Mike", id: 10},{name : "Laura", id: 23},{name : "carl", id: 25},{name : "Lori", id: 23}];
    var arr = []
    for(var i in sheetData){
        var someObject = sheetData[i];
        arr.push(someObject[Object.keys(someObject)[0]]);
    }
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the return statement outside the loop.

```js
function getSheetSectionData(name){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name),
  sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
  data = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++){
      var obj = {};
      obj = sheetData[i][0];
      data.push(obj);
  }
   return data; 
}
```